# Redirect sitename.com/en to sitename.com/ar using htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want to redirect sitename.com/en and all links inside that sections to the same urls with /ar instead of /en using htaccess file. The number of links inside the section is enormous, so I can't write them one by one. Please help...

Answer (score 0):

Use this .htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule   ^en/(.*)?$  /ar/$1 [QSA,L]
```

If you want that old pages (en/) to no longer be used, and see the new url (ar/) in your browser, use `[QSA,L,R=301]` instead of `[QSA,L]` (it notify you're using a permanent redirection)

Comment: although the control panel could recognize the redirect from the htaccess file.. the redirect didn't happen neither in the /en/ main section nor in the insider links.. thank you for replying either way ^_^

Comment: Have you tried the tag `[QSA,L,R=301]` as written ? This code should work. If it doesn't, there's an other configuration point we don't know.

Comment: I tried the tag [QSA,L,R=301] just as written..didn't work.  thanks again

Comment: Is your `.htaccess` file at the root ?

Comment: the .htaccess file is in the document root; it is not the public_html folder. but it is the folder that httpd.conf points to as a documentroot.